# Error en la interfaz gráfica al generar un DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, ms-access

me sucede una cosa muy extraña es un ejercicio muy sencillo lo único que hace es que al pulsar el botón "CONECTAR" me carga un DataGridView de un origen de datos, el problema está que al pulsar el botón toda la interfaz se redimensiona y se hace más pequeña (Foto 2).
- El dataSet corresponde a un Access 2016 (.accdb)
- Estoy utilizando visual studio 2017 (community)
- Windows 10
- El proyecto es: "Aplicación de Windows forms (.net framework)"
- El framework es el 4.6.1
Este es todo el código que tengo:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Me.SociosTableAdapter.Fill(Me.VideoclubDataSet.Socios)
  end Sub

  Private Sub SociosBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As  EventArgs) Handles SociosBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
      Me.Validate()
      Me.SociosBindingSource.EndEdit()
      Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.VideoclubDataSet)
  End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Interfaz al iniciar la aplicacion]

[image: Interfaz al pulsar el boton "CONECTAR"]

Comment: Es posible que tengas activada la propiedad **AutoSize** en algún control y por ello es que la interfaz se muestra mas reducida.

Comment: No, fue de lo primero que mire todos los elementos tienen el autosize en false

Comment: Es muy raro lo que comentas, un Dataset no debería afectar en el diseño de tu form (Bueno al menos eso pienso), podrías probar con esto, (no es la solución optima pero podría servir), dentro de tu button click especifica el ancho y alto de tu form, yo se que no tendría sentido porque ya están definidas en las propiedades de form, pero podrias evitar que se redimensione al momento de dar click!